# Tomcat web.xml documentation

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I am having some issues with deploying a Java app to Tomcat and I wanted to see where the documentation for web.xml is. I can't seem to find it.

I am using a standard web.xml but I would like to know what all the specific xml tags mean.

Of course normally using a standard web.xml just works but I would really like to see some documentation.

I have looked on the Tomcat 7 documentation site but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file **web.xml** is also know as the **deployment descriptor** and is not tomcat-specific. If you want to find some documentation about the deployment descriptor look in the [Java Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-2.4-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/), chapter 13 and also apendixes A and B. (this is for version 2.4, maybe you rather search for the most recent version, 3.1 I think)

Now if you are looking for documentation about the file **web.xml** in *CATALINA_HOME*/conf , the file itself is already well self-documented with internal comments, BTW, the first comment says:

```
  <!-- This document defines default values for *all* web applications      -->
  <!-- loaded into this instance of Tomcat.  As each application is         -->
  <!-- deployed, this file is processed, followed by the                    -->
  <!-- "/WEB-INF/web.xml" deployment descriptor from your own               -->
  <!-- applications.                                                        -->
  <!--                                                                      -->
  <!-- WARNING:  Do not configure application-specific resources here!      -->
  <!-- They should go in the "/WEB-INF/web.xml" file in your application.   -->
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe youll find this [reference guide](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml)
 being usefull

Comment: is a tomcat server and is not working. Perhaps if you copy/paste the snippets of reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean web.xml in conf/web.xml , this is deployment descriptor for default application.

See here http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html

For general web.xml specification you have to check any JEE tutorial .