# Spring mvc, why my controller not mapped

Tags: spring-mvc

I defined my Dispatcher servlet's url mapping in web.xml like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
 <url-pattern>/data/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

my controller's method is annotated with:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/data/sys/CodeCatalogs")
```

when I request the url in browser I got 404 error, if I change the mapping to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/sys/CodeCatalogs")
```

the full url:

```
http://localhost:8080/cwe/data/sys/CodeCatalogs
```

it works, why? I am new to spring mvc, please help.

I tested url that contain no wildcard:

```
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
     <url-pattern>/data/*</url-pattern>
     url-pattern>/test/foo</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

then this request mapping will works:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test/foo")
```

Comment: provide the URL as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
     <url-pattern>/data/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In the preceding example, all requests starting with /data and anything which ends with *.do will be handled by the DispatcherServlet instance named dispatcher.

So for controller's method is annotated with:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/data/sys/CodeCatalogs")

http://localhost:8080/cwe/data/sys/CodeCatalogs - Does not match
http://localhost:8080/cwe/data/data/sys/CodeCatalogs - Does matches
```

URL passes from browser will be first matched against URL pattern specified  and 
then the URL specified in `@RequestMapping`.

For controller's method is annotated with :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test/foo")

http://localhost:8080/cwe/test/foo - Matches since URL matches the exact pattern which is allowed as per Servlet Specification.
http://localhost:8080/cwe/data/test/foo  - This will also match because of pattern /data/*
```

Answer (score 1):

For an incoming request of the form `/data/sys/CodeCatalogs`, your servlet container will consume the `/data/` portion before passing the pattern to your Spring servlet.  So the controller will receive `/sys/CodeCatalogs` and hence this is why your second `@RequestMapping` works and the first does not.

Comment: is this specified in servlet specification or spring mvc documentation?

Comment: Please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153778/tomcat-web-xml-documentation).